# Is there any way to compare nine integers without array in C language?

Tags: c

Lately, I have to do a programming project which is making a course registration system. One of the instructions is to those 9 courses code in ascending order. I have set those course codes as integers but I don't know how to make it without using array... Can anyone teach me ? Thank you with a lot ! The variable names I have adopted is code1,code2,code3,code4,code5,code6,code7,code8,code9...

Comment: are you using C or C#?

Comment: are you wishing to put them in order from a random initial order? From the looks of it `code1,code2,code3,code4,code5,code6,code7,code8,code9` are already in order?

Comment: Anything is possible... https://ideone.com/70aJQh

Comment: First try to do the task with fewer, say 4 variables, then extent it to 5,6,7...

Comment: So why not use an array instead?

Answer (score 0):

> code in ascending order.
>   but I don't know how to make it without using array

Not using an array is a poor idea, yet may be good for learning.

The key idea to to somehow break the problem down into smaller pieces.

The below uses a recursive solution which could incur a recursion depth of `n*n` - not that great.  Leave it to OP to think of a more efficient approach and to extend it to 9 variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *v1, int *v2) {
  int t = *v1;
  *v1 = *v2;
  *v2 = t;
}

void sort4(int *v1, int *v2, int *v3, int *v4) {
  if (*v1 > *v2) swap(v1,v2);
  else if (*v2 > *v3) swap(v2,v3);
  else if (*v3 > *v4) swap(v3,v4);
  else return;
  sort4(v1,v2,v3,v4);
  return;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
    int code1,code2,code3,code4;
    code1 = rand()%1000;
    code2 = rand()%1000;
    code3 = rand()%1000;
    code4 = rand()%1000;
    sort4(&code1, &code2, &code3, &code4);
    printf("%3d %3d %3d %3d\n", code1, code2, code3, code4);
  }
}
```

Output

```
262 529 743 933
256 508 700 752
119 256 351 711
108 393 705 843
169 330 366 932
847 868 917 972
223 549 592 980
164 169 427 551
190 624 635 920
310 484 862 944
```